# How to specify location of image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have some code that will display an image directly over any hyperlinks.  Unfortunately, if the image populates directly over the cursor, there seems to be a conflict:

[Website](http://goo.gl/hBIm28)

You can see that the code works well with small images.  But large images will flicker.  How can I get the images to stop flickering.  I think the location of the displayed image needs to be away from the hyperlink.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("<div id='player-image-hover'></div>").appendTo("body").css("position", "absolute").css("z-index", "1000").css("padding", "2px").css("backgroundColor", "#666");

    jQuery("a[href^='http://thepoolscene.com/player-profile']").each(function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
        title = title.toLowerCase();
        title = ucwords(title);
        var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/" + escape(title) + ".jpg";
        // var o = jQuery(this).offset();
        var that = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'HEAD',
            error: function() { 
                console.log('doesnt exist: ' + url);
            },
            success: function() {
                //var image_preload = new Image(100,25); 
                //image_preload.src = url;
                if (jQuery("#player-image-hover").find("img[src='" + url + "']").length == 0) {
                    jQuery("#player-image-hover").append("<img src='" + url + "' height='220' style='display:none'>");
                }
                jQuery(that).hover(
                    function() {
                      var o = jQuery(this).offset();
                      jQuery("#player-image-hover").css("left", o.left).css("top", o.top-222).css("display", "block").find("img[src='" + url + "']").css("display", "block");
                    },
                    function() {
                      jQuery("#player-image-hover").css("display", "none").find("img").css("display", "none");
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });

});

function ucwords (str) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  // +   improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
  // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // +   improved by: Robin
  // +      input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // *     example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
  // *     returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
  // *     example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
  // *     returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'
  return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function ($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is happening due to the fact that when you hover over a link that has an image covering it, the onmouseout event fires on the link and it hides the image. Then onmouseover is triggered again and the loop continues.

The following plugin may help solve the problem.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

This can add a timeout before the handlerOut is fired.
Plus it supports event delegation in the case you decided to add two types of hovers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to display the image below the link, or if you still want to display it above:

---

You should use javascript to check the height of the image and display the image at the right position ( i.e. Instead of top: `o.top - 222`, you use `o.top - imageHeight` ).

To to this you need to wait for the `onload` event of the image, when it finish loading you will need to get the height of the image, set the position and display it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is happening because the image is loading. It would only flicker briefly (and the image would not entirely appear) were that the case. This flickering is consistent.

I believe that because the larger images are loading *in front of* the links, it is interfering with the browser's interpretation of the mousover/mouseout/hover state of the link and causing the script to fire repeatedly, hiding and revealing the image.

If you have Photoshop you could test this theory pretty easily. Using color mode (CMYK takes more space than RGB takes more space than Greyscale) and JPEG compression you could make physically small images that are relatively large in file size and physically large images that are relatively small in file size.

Now, as for a solution to this problem (other than sticking to smaller images that don't block the link) I'm sure there's a way but it'll have to come from someone more skilled than me. I suspect the answer involves using a timer to limit how often the script can fire (though that will have side effects).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions...  Someone else has provided the solution for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("<div id='player-image-hover'></div>").appendTo("body").css("position", "absolute").css("z-index", "1000").css("padding", "2px").css("backgroundColor", "#666");
jQuery("#player-image-hover").mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery("#player-image-hover").css("display", "none").find("img").css("display", "none");
});

jQuery("a[href^='http://thepoolscene.com/player-profile']").each(function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    title = title.toLowerCase();
    title = ucwords(title);
    var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/" + escape(title) + ".jpg";
    // var o = jQuery(this).offset();
    var that = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'HEAD',
        error: function() { 
            console.log('doesnt exist: ' + url);
        },
        success: function() {
            //var image_preload = new Image(100,25); 
            //image_preload.src = url;
            if (jQuery("#player-image-hover").find("img[src='" + url + "']").length == 0) {
                jQuery("#player-image-hover").append("<img src='" + url + "' height='220' style='display:none'>");
            }
            jQuery(that).mouseenter(function() {
                var o = jQuery(this).offset();
                jQuery("#player-image-hover").css("left", o.left).css("top", o.top-222).css("display", "block").find("img[src='" + url + "']").css("display", "block");
            });
        }
    });
});

});

function ucwords (str) {
// http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
// +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
// +   improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
// +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
// +   improved by: Robin
// +      input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
// +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
// *     example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
// *     returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
// *     example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
// *     returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'
return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g,           function ($1) {
return $1.toUpperCase();
});
}
```